# Set the image in the middle of the DIV in case of nested DIVs

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, kendo-ui

I am trying to set up a image in the center of multiple divs but the Image is still appearing slightly towards right. Below is the JSfiddle link for my code. Please help if anyone knows how ro align it in center.

**[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/piyush_pj/6heug7un/4/)**

```
<div id="TView" class="k-group">
<div id="TestTarget" class="k-group " style="background-color: #323b42">
    <div id="numberCircleDoc" class="numberCircle">3</div>
    <div class="Nav">

        <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/small_icons/misc_7/.cache/teddy_bear.png"  />
        <br />
        <br />TESTING MGMT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to me like its more towards the left. What do you mean by its towards the right?

Comment: Sorry I meant towards left...its a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**[MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6heug7un/20/)**

CSS:

```
.Nav {
    background-color: #12817b;
    height: 117px;
    width: 172px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.Nav:hover {
    background-color: #71B3B0;
}
.numberCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    color: #12817b;
    text-align: center;
    font: 10px Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 4px;
    right: 0;
    position:absolute;
}

#TestTarget {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-style: none;
       position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="TView" class="k-group">
    <div id="TestTarget" class="k-group " style="background-color: #323b42">
        <div id="numberCircleDoc" class="numberCircle">3</div>
        <div class="Nav">

            <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/small_icons/misc_7/.cache/teddy_bear.png"  />
            <br />
            <br />TESTING MGMT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the numberCircle position: absolute, and use top and right to set this element , then the img will be in center